# Comprehending the proof for the addition of limits

Tags: limits, proof-writing, arithmetic

The theorem for the addition of limits:

$\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)\ \pm\ g(x) ] = \lim_{x \to a}f(x)\ \pm\ \lim_{x \to a}g(x) = K + L$

is often proven using the the idea of getting the module of the functions minus the limits to be smaller than $\frac{ε}{2}$:

$|f(x) - L| < \frac{ε}{2}$,

I do understand that doing this is acceptable as we are not working with numbers per se, but rather with constantly smaller numbers, but this idea seems kind of shaky. Why is it allowed for us to simply get a value of $\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ with corresponding $\frac{ε}{2}$ and then simply sum them up to get a whole ε without changing the left part of the inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $\delta$ to be the minimum of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$. This choice of $\delta$ depends only on $\epsilon$, and ensures $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon/2$ and $|g(x)-K| < \epsilon/2$ **both** hold whenever $|x-a| < \delta$. Then the triangle inequality ensures $|f(x)+g(x)-(L+K)| \le |f(x)-L| + |g(x)-K| < \epsilon / 2 + \epsilon / 2=  \epsilon$.

Comment: I get the triangle inequality, but still I cannot understand why I can simply replace δ with $δ_{1}$ and $δ_{2}$ for each function and divide ϵ by 2. As far as I know, it's because ther're just small values, ao there's nothing on the way of getting even smaller numbers, but how I change deltas and epsilons if they depend on each other